# How to control css transition?

Tags: css

I am creating a search bar that accepts search terms from user.I have inserted a CSS transition (it's width increases on click).The problem I am facing is that when i click the submit button the width of the search bar decreases.I don't want that to happen and the search bar should retain its changed width.
Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="    search" id="search">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" >submit </button>  
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
width: 130px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/qetto-2/256/search-icon.png");
background-size:40px;
/*background-position: 10px 10px;*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
margin-left:7%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
width: 75%;
}
```

Here is the link to my code if it helps:
https://codepen.io/ryoko1/pen/eRMYrg?editors=1111

Comment: This [Tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/) will help you a lot to understand and optimize code concept....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem I am facing is that when i click the submit button the width of the search bar decreases.**

That's because as soon as `input losses` it's `focus` it `decrease` it's `input width` back to originally assigned or default width. This even happens when you `click` anywhere else in the page not only `submit button` and reason is it lost focus from input. So do using `jQuery` click() method.

```
$("input[type='text']").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("width","75%");
}); //Add this to your jQuery
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=bill gates";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
 //   console.log(data[1]);
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML("hello");
   // console.log("hello");
  });
  $("input[type='text']").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("width", "75%");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png/800px-Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png");
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/qetto-2/256/search-icon.png");
  background-size: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out .1s;
  margin-left: 7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Wikipedia Viewer</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="    search" id="search">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">submit </button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How does jquery click method help to retain the focus?

Comment: @RohanAkut That worked as a clicked instead when you use focus on input and if it leave target element then input would consider that event as blur, whereas this doesn't happens with click event.

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome @RohanAkut :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use transition delay (set to 100ms):

```
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out .1s;
```

Additional reset delay on focused element:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: The code is still not working properly.Why have you included .1s n the transition?I don't seem to find any reason for it.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: .1s means that after clicking on submit button, the input will wait for 100ms before it folds. You can set more time there to see the effect.